# Disabling various clicks event in this particuar case

Tags: jquery

I have a image slide but if a user multiple click in next or prev button this cause a white space between slides.

This the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CK6LF/2/)

And below is javascript code:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(function() {

var liwidth = $("#galeria ul li").outerWidth(),
speed   = 4000,
rotate  = setInterval(auto, speed)
$("section#galeria").hover(function(e){

    $("section#buttons").fadeIn();

    clearInterval(rotate);
    }, function(){
        $("section#buttons").fadeOut();
        rotate = setInterval(auto, speed);
        });



        $(".next").click(function(e){







            e.preventDefault();
                           $("section#galeria ul").css({'width' : '99999%'}).animate({left:- liwidth}, function(){
            $("#galeria ul li").last().after($("#galeria ul li").first());
            $(this).css({'left':'0', 'width':'auto'

            });
             $('.next').removeClass('active');  

            });




            });



        $(".prev").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();



            $("#galeria ul li").first().before($("#galeria ul li").last().css({'margin-left':-liwidth}) );
            $("section#galeria ul").css({'width':'99999%'}).animate({left:liwidth}, function(){
            $("#galeria ul li").first().css({'margin-left':'0'});   
                $(this).css({'left':'0', 'width':'auto'});

            });




        });

         function auto() {
    $(".next").click();
}


});
```

How to fix this issue or prevent it?

Thank for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m not sure if you can agree with this, but you can try:

1.Disable button after click;

2.Enable it after your action has been done.

Comment: Leo your code is working in the jsFiddle but not working in my local host. Any change beyond the js?

Comment: A =) Thanks ! This solved my question. And i added border:none to button section in the css.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can hide PREV/NEXT button right after click and show it again when animation is over.